# How can I fix this footer?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

So I'm doing a footer with bootstrap, it looks great but when I put in this resolution (image below), a blank space showed it up.

Boostrap Footer:

[image]

This is what I made:

```
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h6>Copyright &copy; 2018</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h6>About us</h6>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget sapien dolor. Nam aliquam augue ante, et sodales felis vulputate iaculis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

footer{
 background: #333;
 color: #eee;
 font-size: 11px;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

How can I fix that?

With nikhil's approach this is happening

[attemp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DZXG.png)

Comment: Could you provide the CSS with your markup?

Comment: There it is....

Comment: just copy paste my code  remove all your css and all html take my code its working fine

Comment: Isn't working, i've just copied your code to an fiddle and added some text. Try to decrease the width and you'll see that the footer cut the text at some point. https://jsfiddle.net/jamesmort/qgjcxrum/

Comment: i saw it the footer is working fine its divided into two blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that's what you want but you can just add `style="min-height:100vh"` to your page content container and place footer in another container.

This way your footer will always be at the bottom of your page.

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion and seems to work, but in a small content page there will be a very large space, any suggestions how to improve this matter?

Answer (score -1):

this will work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .footer {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <h6>Copyright &copy; 2018</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <h6>About us</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget sapien dolor. Nam aliquam augue
                            ante, et sodales felis vulputate iaculis.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

**fiddle**:https://jsfiddle.net/rq3eab2v/2/

if you are using bootstrap 4 use col-* instead of col-xs-* ok

Comment: Thanks for helping, but now when it's full screen the footer is cutting the paragraph

Comment: how do you want it to be rendered??

Comment: @JasonMort now check its working properly. please upvote it and give it a green tick.

Comment: I want the footer to stay always at the bottom and be responsive, Resizing every time that I resize the browser

Comment: the green tick on the left side of question it will help others to get the solution

Comment: I put in the question the attempt using your code, it's still cutting the paragraph

Comment: resize the browser window

Comment: @mahan its working perfectly on all devices what nonsense are you talking about

Comment: @nikhilsugandh  bootstrap-4 does not have `*-xs-*` classes. They have tagged `bootstrap-4`, not `bootstrap-3`

Comment: you are giving whatever comes to your mind to OP hasnt said anywhere  he is using bootstrap 4

Answer (score -1):

**`Position fixed`** removes element from the normal flow of the content. Therefore, you need to use **`bottom: 0;`** to position the footer at the very bottom.

```css
.postion-b-0 {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

---

Most of your css code is unnecessary. You need to use only the property above.

```css
.postion-b-0 {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer class="position-fixed container-fluid bg-dark text-white py-5 postion-b-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 ">
      <h6>Copyright &copy; 2018</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <h6>About us</h6>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget sapien dolor. Nam aliquam augue ante, et sodales felis vulputate iaculis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

---

The columns takes half of the rows in the code above. But if you want full width column on mobile, use the code below.

```css
.postion-b-0 {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer class="position-fixed container-fluid bg-dark text-white py-5 postion-b-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 ">
      <h6>Copyright &copy; 2018</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
      <h6>About us</h6>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget sapien dolor. Nam aliquam augue ante, et sodales felis vulputate iaculis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```